How to manually adjust a decision tree obtained from rpart, including surrogate splits?
I built a decision tree with surrogate splits using rpart. Now, after inspection of the tree by a subject matter expert, the tree needs some small manual adjustment (addition of an extra branch).
Initially I thought 'No problem, I'll just write out the tree as a series of ifelse statements and adjust where needed'. However, I didn't think of the surrogate splits.
Is it possible to extract the rules, including those for the surrogate splits, in a easy to read format? Using summary() on the decision tree object is a bit difficult to interpret honestly. For example following output, I don't know how to interpret it. E.g. what does RL-- mean, knowing that my variables are categorical with values '-' or '+'?
  Surrogate splits:
      var1 splits as  RL--, agree=0.841, adj=0.109, (0 split)
      var2 splits as  RL--, agree=0.838, adj=0.094, (25 split)
      var3 splits as  RL--, agree=0.830, adj=0.047, (0 split)
      var4 splits as  RL--, agree=0.827, adj=0.031, (0 split)

If there would be a way to extract and convert the decision tree's (incl. surrogate splits) logic to R-code (ifelse statements?) in a programmatic manner, that would be ideal.
I found some info on converting the main logic (without surrogate splits) to rules, however none about the surrogate splits.
Someone asked a reproducible example.
set.seed(42)
iris_with_na <- iris

iris_with_na[,1] <- sample(c("+", "-"), nrow(iris), replace = TRUE)
iris_with_na[,2] <- sample(c("+", "-"), nrow(iris), replace = TRUE)
iris_with_na[,3] <- sample(c("+", "-"), nrow(iris), replace = TRUE)
iris_with_na[,4] <- sample(c("+", "-"), nrow(iris), replace = TRUE)

iris_with_na[sample(nrow(iris), 15, replace = F), 1] <- NA
iris_with_na[sample(nrow(iris), 15, replace = F), 2] <- NA
iris_with_na[sample(nrow(iris), 15, replace = F), 3] <- NA
iris_with_na[sample(nrow(iris), 15, replace = F), 4] <- NA

mytree <- rpart::rpart(Species ~ ., data = iris_with_na)

summary(mytree)


let's look at the first part of the output after the variable importance info:
Node number 1: 150 observations,    complexity param=0.09
  predicted class=setosa      expected loss=0.6666667  P(node) =1
    class counts:    50    50    50
   probabilities: 0.333 0.333 0.333 
  left son=2 (73 obs) right son=3 (77 obs)
  Primary splits:
      Sepal.Width  splits as  LR, improve=1.3745280, (15 missing)
      Petal.Length splits as  RL, improve=0.3862095, (15 missing)
      Sepal.Length splits as  LR, improve=0.3251852, (15 missing)
      Petal.Width  splits as  LR, improve=0.0984127, (15 missing)
  Surrogate splits:
      Sepal.Length splits as  RL, agree=0.519, adj=0.015, (14 split)

How do I interpret things like Sepal.Length splits as  RL
R and L are probably right and left, but it doesn't say what goes left and what goes right. This is information I would like to know.
I can't replicate the RL-- I am having, though (see output above).
What I ultimately want to do is to translate the tree to something like this (only showing first split for brevity, and the example is no way related to the previously shown output):
#pseudocode

dplyr::case_when(variable_at_first_node == "+" ~ left_logic,
variable_at_first_node == "-" ~ right_logic,
is.na(variable_at_first_node) ~ surrogate_split_logic)


and then add somewhere a branch manually (based on the expert's input), but that would not be what my question is about.
My question is about the surrogate_split_logic: how do I extract this from the rpart object?
Or, if there are easier ways to achieve what I want, I'd be happy to hear about them.

It's easier to help you if you include a simple reproducible example with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

This is only an answer to the question regarding the interpretation of the output.
I still don't know what the dashes mean, but
 var1 splits as  RL--

means that the first level of the categorical variable var1 splits to the right and the second level to the left.
Using this knowledge I was able to use the output from summary(mytree) to write out all the logic and alter the tree. However, this approach is very tedious and error prone.
